# Pause the Views from Updating

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

Want to pause the multiple views from updating when Pause button is pressed

In h file

```
@property BOOL appIsPaused;
```

In m file

```
@synthesize appIsPaused;

-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

      [audioPlayer pause];

      appIsPaused = YES;

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [audioPlayer play];

      appIsPaused = NO;

      [self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:11.0];

  }  

}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:23];

[viewController release];

}

-(void)secondViewController {
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self performSelector:@selector(ThirdviewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:27];

[secondController release];
}
```

and it goes on like this for multiple views.

Any ideas how to pause views from updating whenever pause button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using performSelector after delay, you should consider using a NSTimer.

Like this:

Declare a NSTimer *timer ivar.
Declare a NSUInteger viewControl;

Set viewControl to 0;

On the play part of the method add this line:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)tick
{
    switch(viewControl)
    {
        case 0:
            [self performSelector:@selector(firstViewController) withObject:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
           [self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil];
            break;
        case 2:
           [self performSelector:@selector(thirdViewController) withObject:nil];
           break;
        .
        .
        .
        default:
            break;
    }

    viewControl++;

    if(viewControl > MAX_VIEWS)
    {
         viewControl = 0;
    }
}
```

And add this line on pause action:

```
[timer invalidate]
```

It is also cleaner and let you have more control over your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your was little complex so i used this instead  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
          
and after pause action i added [timer invalidate]; it worked but when pause button got hit again to resume playback then views are not updating but audiofile is playing. I want views to be updated based on timer given when pause button hit again to resume playback. How i can do that.

Comment: You just have to call  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: again. Add this code to the play part of the method. Simple as that.

Comment: I will update my answer with a better approach. It is wrong to use timerInterval in the switch. You will have to create a control to map which is the next view to call. That way, you will not be going always to the first image when play again.

Comment: what piece of code i have to add just this call scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: after the statement [audioplayer play]; actually i added [timer isValid]; after the statement [audioplayer play]; but seems like not working

Comment: But with every view timer is changed based on the stanza length

Comment: [timer isValid] is only to check whether the time has been invalidated or if its still running. You will have to add  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: again after [audioplayer play].

Comment: So i should just add this scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: after [audioplayer play].

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8196/discussion-between-raphael-ayres-and-user1120133)